# Text direction from right to left in cleditor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cleditor

I have a form in arabic language it uses `cleditor`  for textarea's. How to make the text direction of cleditor from right to left and the cursor must point to the end of text when typed.javascript code tried is as follows:

```
 function rtl(element)
    {   
        if(element.setSelectionRange){
            element.setSelectionRange(0,0);
        }
    }
 <textarea name="test" id="test"   onkeyup="rtl(this);"></textarea>
```

Can anyone help!!!!

Comment: text field (as in `input` tag) or `textarea`? can you not use `contenteditable div`? also show sample of what you have tried till now.

Comment: @harry its textarea.Actually my form is in arabic,so the textarea direction must be from right to left.i have tried cleditor but could not change the text direction from left to right.I haven't tried another way,searching a way out.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle (of your code with cleditor)? I will try to help you in changing text direction.

Comment: @harry,http://jsfiddle.net/fp6A6/10/.Toolbar image is not there as the image path is not correct but options will work.

Comment: Check if this is what you need mate. If it solves your problem, I will add it as the answer. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/fp6A6/11/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just have to do the below in-order to change the text direction in CLEditor.

```
$("#test").cleditor({
                      bodyStyle: "direction:rtl"
                    });
```

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/fp6A6/11/) for a demo.

Answer (score -1):

You can use tinyMCE Editor

Refer : http://www.tinymce.com/enterprise/using.php

Comment: ,Actually my form is in arabic,so the textarea direction must be from right to left.Is direction change possible using tinyMCE?